# Question regarding a proof that derivatives of injective holomorphic functions are nonzero.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Proposition:** Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$
  be an open path connected set and suppose $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$
  is holomorphic and injective. Then $f'\left(z_{0}\right)\neq0$
  for all $z_{0}\in\Omega$
 .

**Proof:** WLOG we can assume that $0\in\Omega$
  and $z_{0}=f\left(z_{0}\right)=0$
 . Assume that $f^{'}\left(0\right)=0$
 , thus $f$
  has a zero of order $m\geq2$
  at $0$
 . Since $f$
  is injective we know that this is an isolated zero of $f$
  and thus there is a $\delta>0$
  such that $f$
  doesn't have zeros on the boundary of the ball $B\left(0,\delta\right)$
 . Define $2\varepsilon=\inf_{\left|z\right|=\delta}\left|f\left(z\right)\right|>0$
 . We will show that for each $\omega\in B\left(0,\varepsilon\right)$
  the equation $f\left(z\right)=\omega$
  has $m$
  distinct solutions in $B\left(0,\delta\right)$
 . Define $\varphi\left(z\right)=f\left(z\right)-\omega$
 , we can see that for all $z\in\partial B\left(0,\delta\right)$
 : $$\left|f\left(z\right)-\varphi\left(z\right)\right|=\left|\omega\right|<\varepsilon<2\varepsilon\leq\left|f\left(z\right)\right|+\left|\varphi\left(z\right)\right|$$
 Thus from Rouche's Theorem the equations $f\left(z\right)=0$
  and $f\left(z\right)=\omega$
  have the same number of zeros in $B\left(0,\delta\right)$
 . Since we already know that $f\left(z\right)=0$
  has exactly $m$
  solutions at $B\left(0,\delta\right)$
  we get that $f\left(z\right)=\omega$
  also has $m$
  solutions.
At this point something was said that I somehow completely missed regarding why the solutions for $f\left(z\right)=\omega$
  are also distinct, I would appreciate it if someone could fill up this hole for me.

Once we know that solutions are distinct we obviously get a contradiction to $f$ being injective and that concludes the proof.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The point is to reach a contradiction to injectivity. What I wrote up to the point of what I missed gives us that $f\left(z\right)-\omega$ has $m$ zeros but they might be one zero of order $m$ which would provide no contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One point that is lacking in the exposition, but crucial to the argument that every $\omega \in B_{\varepsilon}(0)\setminus\{0\}$ is attained at $m$ *distinct* points in $B_\delta(0)$, is that the zeros of $f'$ are discrete, and that $\delta$ is chosen such that $0$ is the only zero of $f'$ in $\overline{B_\delta(0)}$.

Then, since $0$ is the only value that can be attained with multiplicity greater than $1$ in $B_\delta(0)$, the distinctness follows.

Comment: The reason I can pick such $\delta$ is that otherwise I would have a sequence of zeros of $f^{'}$ which would mean $f^{'}\equiv0$ and thus $f$ is constant in contradiction, right?

Comment: Right. If $f'$ has a non-isolated zero, it vanishes identically by the identity theorem, and then $f$ is constant, and certainly not injective.

Comment: Regarding the phrasing of $Rouché's$ theorem, there is a "symmetric version" mentioned in Wikipedia (which is the one we proved in the course I'm taking) and it's a slightly stronger version I believe since requiring $\left|f-\varphi\right|<\left|f\right|+\left|\varphi\right|$ is a weaker requirement than $\left|f-\varphi\right|<\left|f\right|$

Comment: Ah, okay. Anything that guarantees that $\lambda\cdot f + (1-\lambda)\cdot \varphi$ has no zeros on the boundary for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ works. Didn't expect an unusual version to show up.

Comment: Small followup question: The proof I've seen of Rouché′s theorem uses the Argument Principle and the proof I've seen of the Argument Principle uses the Residue Theorem. In particular the residue theorem requires a domain that contains a path that is homotopic to a trivial path. Shouldn't that thus be a requirement of Rouché′s theorem and thus the claim I mentioned here also?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The residue theorem says the integral over a closed path [cycle, more accurately] is the sum of (winding number)×residue, in the case that the path [cycle] is the [union of] boundary curve[s] of a nice open set, all winding numbers are $1$. The special cases of the residue theorem Argument principle/Rouché's theorem require a nice open set, so that its boundary is an admissible chain of paths of integration, nothing more. A disk certainly is nice in that sense.

Comment: The formulation of the Residue Theorem as I've seen it assumed that the function in question was defined in a simply connected domain and the path of integration and its interior were contained in said domain. But indeed I see now that for boundaries of "nice" open sets you don't need to require anything.

Comment: That would be the local residue theorem, maybe. Where you integrate around a single isolated singularity. But then usually one takes a "sufficiently small" circle around the singularity.