# Checking whether the following statements are true or not

Tags: complex-analysis

I found in one of my exams the following true/false question:

> 1. Let $G$ be a domain in $\Bbb C$ with $G\cap\Bbb R\ne\emptyset$. If $f$ is a holomorphic function in $G$ that takes real values in a non-empty interval $I\subset G\cap\Bbb R$, then $f$ takes real values in $G\cap\Bbb R$.
> 2. If $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)|\ge |z|^{27}$ for all $z\in\Bbb C$ with $|z|>10^6$, then $f$ is a polinomic function of degree at least $27$.
> 3. If $D$ is open in $\Bbb C$ and $f:D\to \Bbb C$ is holomorphic and injective in $D$, then $f'(z)\ne0$ for all $z\in D$.

For the first statement, I found [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712721/a-holomorphic-function-that-only-takes-real-values-on-an-interval-takes-only-rea) which is similar to this one but for $G = \Bbb C$. Could a similar process be applied for any $G\subsetneq\Bbb C$ with the established restrictions?

For the second statement, I know that if $|f(z)|\le|z|^{27}$ then there exists $\lambda\in\Bbb C$ such that $f(z)=\lambda z^{27}$, but I don't know how to reach a similar conclusion with $|f(z)|\ge|z|^{27}$. Perhaps we have to find a counterexample instead?

Apparently, the third statement is a well-known result, and I've found some questions about it in here. However, I fail to understand the proofs in said questions. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625042/question-regarding-a-proof-that-derivatives-of-injective-holomorphic-functions-a) is the closest I can get to understand, but even there I struggle with it. Could anyone please explain it to me, or maybe summarize the important aspects of the proof?

Comment: Try the consider the first statement first and compare it with the duplicate. Where does it matter in the proof that the domain is not the whole of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: I noticed that the intersection $G\cap\Bbb R$ isn't necessarily connected. Could that be relevant?

Comment: 1 is false see my answer to the question here with the tubular neighborhood counterexample for $\sqrt z$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3883510/is-fx-in-mathbbr-if-x-in-mathbbr/3883579#3883579

Comment: Oh, what a simple counterexample. Thanks for answering! Two more to go!

Comment: 2 is true because it implies that $f\to \infty$ at infinity  so it is a polynomial  etc

Comment: For 3 the easiest way is to note that by the argument  principle the equation $f(z)-w=0$ has a constant  number of solutions in a small enough neighborhood of any point $(z_0,w_0=f(z_0)$ for a non constant analytic $f$ there; any root of the derivative gives that number to be at least two in a small neighborhood so the function cannot be injective

Comment: Oh, I see 3 now. Thank you so much! Could you please explain a bit further why you can say directly that $f$ is polinomial in 2?